# Counting XML Tags

Tags: php, xml, count

How would I go about counting all of the XML elements? I would like to find how many times the `<product>` tag is used. For example:

```
<root>
   <product>
   </product>
   <product>
   </product>
   <product> 
   </product>
</root>
```

I know that there is a simplexml function called count, but I am not exactly sure how this would go about working. If someone could take the time to post an example and explain the count function, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$xml->product->count();`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can also use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

For example:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<root>
   <product>
   </product>
   <product>
   </product>
   <product>
   </product>
</root>
SOURCE;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);

$elements = $xml->xpath('/root/product');
echo count($elements);
```

Will result in:

> 3

Comment: How about loading a file? I could just use `simplexml_load_file`?

Comment: Yes you can use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), for example `$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that comes to mind.

```
// Get content
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$root = $xpath->evaluate("/root/products");
echo $root->length;
```

Comment: How about in simplexml?

Comment: You can do `$productCount = $xpath->evaluate("count(/root/products)");` and fetch the value directly. This is not possbile with SimpleXML.